# Hashtag search in Facebook API

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to find in Facebook API if they provide the HashTag search.

I meant I search in Facebook Query language and searched in Facebook Tool Explorer.

Any Idea ?

[image]

Comment: http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/NcJP200113-Custom-Razor-View-Engine-for-C

Comment: "Note
Use one of the approach when you are sure that you will use only either C# language or VB Language. It will be helpful to you.
If you are using both type of views (cshtml and vbhtml), don't implement this."

Comment: @AdamZuckerman: That's good point. Thanks. Any idea how can i add VB in View Engine for c# project

Comment: With the separation between VB and C#, I don't think it is possible in the same project. You could add another project that is VB based to create a DLL used in your C# project to provide those features. I can't imagine that being easy or quick though.

Comment: Why did you tag this with PHP, WP? I'm supposing it's only for the exposure...

Comment: Sorry but I think your only real option at the moment is using one of the other mentioned "hacks" as a native route is just not available for the general public...see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23865311/1815624).

Answer (score 14):

Since April 30th and the introduction of Facebook api v2.0, public Post search is [no longer available](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) and will return :

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#11) Post search has been deprecated", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 11
  }
}
```

According to Facebook changelog v1.0 will continue to work until April 30th, 2015. As the search endpoint is [back in the v2 doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0), there is hope that they will reconsider the deprecation.

The search endpoint is a fulltext search, you just have to encode the hash (%23) and run your query through it :

### Facebook API explorer :

You have to select **v1.0** or **Unversioned** in the API version selector (on the top right)

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=post&q=%23the_hash_tag
```

### Curl or whatever :

Just remove `/v2.0/` from the url and call the unversioned API

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN&type=post&q=%23the_hash_tag
```

Comment: This says "An unknown error has occured" - access token must be correct as it's a different error message when I change the token. However it works when I change the type from post to place, maybe post isn't supported anymore? The API documentation doesn't contain the "post"-type as well, but how am I now fetching public posts by hashtag?

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no API for the hashtags feature on Facebook
There is a posts search function which will return some posts with a certain hashtag if you use that hashtag as the search string. But it will ignore the # tag. 
There is a comment on one of the sites which says "you can change the # with the hex value from the ascii table (%23) to search for hashtags. but it will only find tags, created by the facebook homepage or official facebook applications." Not sure how valid, you could try it
like this https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%23myhashtag
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%23myhashtag

Answer (score 2):

There is no hashtag API available for Facebook and using %23 for #(hash) is the only solution as of now which already everyone here has commented upon.

I'm not too sure about FQL being deprecated in near future as I could see different opinions across the board.

Answer (score 2):

As I am understanding you would use Keyword Insights API
Though as mentioned on the following link

> Access to the Keyword Insights API is restricted to a limited set of
>   media publishers and usage requires prior approval by Facebook. You
>   cannot apply to use the API at this time.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/keyword_insights/

Take note on the mention of hashtag searching in the "best practices" section.