# How to search with facebook API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, search

I'm try to search post with hashtag that I wrote on my page, but API returns me empty array.

```
$str = 'https://graph.facebook.com/search?q='.urlencode('#englishwordssearch‬') . '&access_token=' . $values['access_token'] . '&appsecret_proof=' . $proof;
```

For some q I get results, but not that I search.
Why I can't find my own post with hashtag?

Comment: Can you see your post if you remove the # from your q parameter?

Comment: no, all the same it's empty array

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22056688/hashtag-search-in-facebook-api/23804047#23804047

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further reading it appears that there is no API support for hashtags at this time. See [How can we track hashtags with the new facebook hashtag implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114210/how-can-we-track-hashtags-with-the-new-facebook-hashtag-implementation) for more details.